# Google Analytics and IE Browser

Tags: internet-explorer-7, google-analytics

Anyone can explain me why below works in Firefox but not in IE.

```
function bookingSubmit(myform) {
 _gaq.push(['_linkByPost', myform, true]);
 return true;
}

<form id="booking-form" action="https://myurl.com" method="get" onsubmit="return bookingSubmit(this);">
<input type="text" name="whatever"/>
<input type="submit" name="Send"/>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `return` part of the `onsubmit`.

Comment: Nope, already tried that. Is actually the same ! Thanks anyway

Comment: Dunno why that's happening, but try this instead <form id="booking-form" action="https://myurl.com" method="get" onsubmit="bookingSubmit(this);return false;">

And then change 'return true' in the function to setTimeout('document.location = "' + myform.href + '"', 100).

I should add that this is the method GA recommends, possibly because of IE problems. See here: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Comment: Does it work if you just call `onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this, true]);"`?

Comment: Wrap a `if (_gaq)` around the `_gaq.push` call first and you'll know if you have it available to work with before calling the `push` method.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a silly question, but where is the GA code that defines _gaq? Head, or body of your document?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you have placed the Google Analytics code in the `<head>` of your page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think there is a bug affecting this method in IE when you pass in an argument to append the cookie values to the hash portion of a URI.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine for me in IE6+.

```
<form id="booking-form" action="https://myurl.com" method="get" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this, true]);">
  <input type="text" name="whatever"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Send"/>
</form>
```